# Joining $4 \times 1$ vectors defined through functions to form a $4 \times n$ matrix

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, vector

I define a $4x1 $column vector through a variable as:

```
Z[i_]:=List[{a[i]},{b[i]},{c[i]},{d[i]}]
```

I then want to make a $4\times  n$ matrix by joining a specified number of these columns together. By other posts on StackExchange, I've found that by using `Join[Z[1],Z[2],Z[3],2]`, and transposing as needed, I can get the form I desire, except that this has dimensions of $4\times 4\times 1$, with an extra `List` around each of the terms in the matrix.

How can I combine columns as one would normally expect by writing them down? Is there a way to automate this where I can specify how many columns I want to combine, i.e to make a specified $4\times n$ matrix rather than 'manually' combining my desired dimension?

EDIT: The desired form of the matrix (through the definition of the Z function is [image: this kind of image here], a $4\times 4$ matrix. The result I get using the `Join` function with an attempt at automation (which I could extend with the `Range` function is [image: this], which has the extra dimension that I don't want.

Comment: what is the desired output for n =3?  `Join[Z[1],Z[2],Z[3],2]` does give a 4X3 matrix.

Comment: As an example for n=4 which is my lowest case, I will upload the desired result as an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
n = 4; 
Join[## & @@ Z /@ Range[n], 2]
```

> {{a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4]}, {b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4]}, {c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4]}, {d[1], d[2], d[3], d[4]}}

```
TeXForm@MatrixForm@%
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  a(1) & a(2) & a(3) & a(4) \\
>  b(1) & b(2) & b(3) & b(4) \\
>  c(1) & c(2) & c(3) & c(4) \\
>  d(1) & d(2) & d(3) & d(4) \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. May you explain why it works? How is it different to what I attempted?

Comment: @Brad, `Join` takes a `Sequence` of lists followed by an integer (specifying the level) . `##&@@{a,b,c}` turns the list `{a,b,c}` too `Sequence[a,b,c]` which is what `Join` needs. (Btw, `##&@@{a,b,c}` is same as `Sequence@@{a,b,c}`. And `foo@@bar[stuff]` gives `foo[stuff]` , i.e., it replaces the `Head` (`bar`) with `foo`)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've seen these # and & symbols thrown around a lot, I'll go do some more research as to what these actually do (I think it's something to do with Slots?). I've accepted your answer. Best wishes.

Comment: @Brad, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 2):

```
Z[i_] := List[{a[i]}, {b[i]}, {c[i]}, {d[i]}]
Transpose[Flatten@*Z /@ Range[5]]
```

or simpler:

```
Z[i_] := {a[i], b[i], c[i], d[i]}
Transpose[Z /@ Range[5]]
```

You are going to make yourself unhappy if you stick to using $n \times 1$ matrices instead of $n$-vectors.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your second answers gives me the same problem as before, but the first one works like a charm. I tried using Flatten, but can you explain why your one works? What does each component do?

Comment: Also, may you elaborate about the nx1 matrices vs n-vectors?